# Очередь предстоящих событий в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

У меня должна сначала выполниться библиотека magnificPopup:

```js
$('#block').on('click', function() {
  $.when(
    $.magnificPopup.open({
      items: {
        src: 'https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/',
        type: 'ajax'
      }
    })
  ).then(function() {
    alert('Вот пример того, что запускается сначала alert, а только потом открывается модальное окно');
    $('.span').addClass('speed-in');
  });
});
```

```css
.span {
  color: #000;
}

.speed-in {
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="#" id="block">Нажмите</a><br/>
<span class="span">Меняет цвет</span>
```

Вообщем у меня должно выполняться сначала открытие информации с другой страницы в модальном окне (в примере кода, сайт не откроется), а затем только надо выполнить добавление класса к span. Так как по идее этот span будет находиться, как раз на другой странице, которую вызываю в модальном окне.

Как мне определить очередность выполнения, подскажите, пожалуйста, уважаемые эксперты?

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен, то ли это, что вам нужно, но у этого плагина есть коллбэки: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api

С их помощью можно вызывать различные события в различные моменты, в том числе и после того, как попап открылся.

Выгляди это так:

```
$('#block').on('click', function() {
  $.magnificPopup.open({
      items: {
        src: 'https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/',
        type: 'ajax'
      },
      callbacks: {
        open: function()  {
          $('.span').addClass('speed-in');
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: К сожалению, не работает(

Comment: `beforeClose` и `Close` почему-то работают, а `open` нет.

Comment: Вам может подойти коллбэк change. Он срабатывает, когда изменен контент попапа. Как, понимаю, именно это и нужно. К сожалению, я сейчас не до конца понимаю проблему потому что ваш пример вообще не вызывает попапа и не работает с данными. Есть ощущение, что проблема не в колбэке.

Comment: `change` я тоже пробовал (не работает), а в примере он и не будет работать попап, так как я пытаюсь подключить обычный внешний сайт (насколько я понял это не возможно, хотя может ошибаюсь, надо лучше изучить документацию), у меня на локальном сервере всё работает, указываю просто путь к нужному подключаемому виду (к нужной папке и шаблону) и открывается отлично этот вид. Пока решил проблему так: сразу добавить в подключаемом шаблоне классы, которые должны по идее добавляться только после открытия попап. Напишу, если что:)

Comment: А у вас этот span вообще в DOM находится таким образом. Попробуйте вывести console.log($('.span')); в реализации с коллбэком open.

Comment: `span` находится в подключаемом виде (когда попап открылся он присутствует), то есть в `DOM` до вызова попап `span` вообще нет:) Поэтому, если добавлять класс сразу, то его просто не найдет. Надеюсь поняли.

Comment: Так не надо сразу. Вы добавьте этот console.log в коллбэк. И не open, наверное. Там у них есть колбэк ajaxContentAdded. Попробуйте его. Вот таким образом, как в документации: console.log(this.content);

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!